# EEPROM programming in Evaluation Board (ADRF6720-27)

Tags: eeprom

I have a ADRF6720-27 EVAL Board. It connects to the host PC using CY7C68013a; the board also has a 64Kb EEPROM 24LC641; ADRF6720-27 is a RF modulator which is programmed via its SPI pins connected to pins 33, 34 and 35 of CY7C68013a.

The evaluation software runs fine. What I want to do is to load a program into the EEPROM (24LC641) such that the board generates stepped frequency from 700MHz to 2GHz.

I suppose this can be achieved if the program drives the three GPIO pins (say 33, 34, 35 in CY7C68013a) to drive the SPI slave (ADRF 6720-27) using bit-banging.

Installing the FX2LP-USB software detects the board correctly. My question is: in the IDE Keil uVision, which header files do I include while writing the program? There are many files in a demo project like bulkloop.c, which ones do I modify and which ones should be left as it is for my own purpose mentioned in the 1st and 2nd paragraph?

Thanks